# Separate Django model field to another fields

Tags: django, orm, model, django-orm

I have a field called *fullname* that has data something like this:

```
first_name:Gholi;last_name:Sezavar Poor Asl Esfahani
```

I want to separate it as two separate fields name first_name & last_name.

My models.py is:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):

    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    information = models.CharField(max_length=350, null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    id_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    born_in = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    birth_year = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
```

and I want to make custom migration for it and using annotate method.
How can I do this ???

***EDIT:***

I want to do this in custom migration and use annotate method like I have done it right now, but now with my code it just stores firstname and last name in first_name field :

```
def organize_person_schema(apps, schema_editor):
    # Person = apps.get_model('people', 'Person')
    Person.objects.annotate(
        first_name_change=Replace(
            F('fullname'), text=Value("first_name:"),
            replacement=Value(''),
            output_field=CharField()
        )
    ).update(first_name=F('first_name_change'))
    Person.objects.annotate(
        last_name_change=Replace(
            F('first_name'), text=Value(";last_name:"),
            replacement=Value(' '),
            output_field=CharField()
        )
    ).update(first_name=F('last_name_change'))
    Person.objects.annotate(
        last_name_last=Concat(
            F('first_name'), Value(""),
            output_field=CharField()
        )
    ).update(last_name=F('last_name_last'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a custom save method to do some update:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):

    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    information = models.CharField(max_length=350, null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    id_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    born_in = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    birth_year = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            # logic to separate full name into first and last
            # Split by (";")
            first_name, last_name = self.fullname.split(";")
            self.first_name = first_name.split(":")[1]
            self.last_name = last_name.split(":")[1]
            super(Person, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```